# Running multiple SFDX source conversion commands concurrently. Any problems?

Tags: salesforcedx

We have Jenkins setup where it is possible to have **multiple builds running concurrently on the same machine**. The only SFDX commands that we use are *force:mdapi:convert* and *force:source:convert*.

So far we have not noticed any issues but wanted to ensure that there are no potential internal lockings between the concurrent command executions.

I am aware of the various commands that need to share the .sfdx context. But for us, we only use SFDX as pure binary function to help with source conversion and nothing else.

I don't have enough internal understanding of the SFDX CLI to make this judgement but would appreciate comments from anyone in this forum.

Thanks.